# vim toggle based on var previous value

Tags: vim

How to switch the value of `mouse` from empty to `a` and vice-versa?

I'm finding myself switching a lot from those two modes. `a` is very nice when i'm a long time in the huge source file and have to use the scroll wheel to navigate, etc.

but dumb mouse mode is just perfect to copy/paste from anywhere to anywhere.

I currently have in my .vimrc:

```
nmap <F11> :se mouse=<CR>
nmap <F12> :se mouse=a<CR>
```

but would be nice to have F11 free again (i'm out of F keys) and have F12 toggle that value... anyone have the recipe for that handy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Heptite is right that you're just curing the symptoms with the toggling, but anyhow, here's how you'd toggle this:

```
:nnoremap <F12> :let &mouse=(empty(&mouse) ? 'a' : '')<CR>
```

- Note: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- Note: For simple boolean on/off options, you can use `:set inv{optionname}`.

Comment: thanks! and thanks for the extra hints! will surely adopt `nnoremap`  ...for my boolean toggles i use a simple `!` as in `nmap <F7> :se wrap!<CR>`

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at:

```
:help 'paste'
:help 'pastetoggle'
```

(The single-quotes are meant to be typed as part of the command.)

Specifically, this will do what you want:

```
:set pastetoggle=<F12>
```

Comment: i'm not wanting to paste into vim. I usually use `mouse=` to easily COPY FROM vim. vim file, double click and drag, middle click in another terminal... and then i may want to change to `mouse=a` to navigate the code with the scroll-wheel.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that to copy from Vim. Perhaps you need to set your 'clipboard' option, though.

Comment: if you access vim via a ssh session, lets say putty, and have `mouse=a`, when you select some text, it is not automatically put on the remote box clipboard. because vim is using the mouse movement, not the console emulator. when you have `mouse=` vim does not use the mouse, so the console emulator is using it to hightlight/copy from the terminal output it is displaying. i could use `mouse=a` and then press `"+y` after selecting in vim. but that is too much trouble :)